# Prove a map is linear ... or not

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $F[x]$ denote the vector space of polynomials in the variable $x$ with coefﬁcients in $F$. Let $e_1 : F[x]\to F$ denote the map taking a polynomial $f$ to $f(1)$ $\in$ $F$. Prove or disprove $e_1$ is linear.

To begin with I have no idea what $F[x]$ is. What does it mean to be a vector space of polynomials IN the variable $x$?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

$F[x]$ is the set of all polynomials in one variable, named $x$, with coefficients in the field $F$:
$$
F[x]=\{a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots+a_nx^n\mid a_0,\ldots,a_n\in F,\ n\in\mathbb{N}\}.
$$
Note that we can view $F[x]$ as a vector space over $F$ by defining scalar multiplication and vector addition. If $\alpha\in F$ is a scalar, and $f,g\in F[x]$ are the polynomials
$$\tag{1}
f(x)=b_0+b_1x+\cdots+b_nx^n,\qquad g(x)=c_0+c_1x+\cdots+c_nx^n
$$
(where the polynomial of lower degree will have zeroes for its highest coefficients), then we define $\alpha\cdot f$ to be the polynomial
$$\tag{2}
(\alpha\cdot f)(x):=\alpha\cdot f(x)=\alpha b_0+\alpha b_1x+\cdots+\alpha b_nx^n
$$
and we define $f+g$ to be the polynomial
$$\tag{3}
(f+g)(x):=f(x)+g(x)=(b_0+c_0)+(b_1+c_1)x+\cdots+(b_n+c_n)x^n.
$$

Now: given $F[x]$, there is a family of natural functions $\phi_a:F[x]\rightarrow F$ for $a\in F$ defined by
$$
\phi_a(f):=f(a)=b_0+b_1a+b_2a^2+\cdots+b_na^n.
$$
(These are called the *evaluation maps*, I believe.) This problem asks about $\phi_1$ in particular, where $1$ is the multiplicative identity in the field $F$. How does $\phi_1$ behave? Using the field properties, we see
$$\tag{4}
\phi_1(f)=f(1)=b_0+b_1\cdot1+b_2\cdot1^2+\cdots+b_n\cdot 1^n=b_0+b_1+\cdots+b_n.
$$

So, the question here is this: is $\phi_1$ a linear mapping? In other words, for $f$ and $g$ as written in (1), $\alpha\cdot f$ and $f+g$ as defined in (2) and (3) respectively, and $\phi_1$ the mapping from (4) that takes a polynomial and gives back the sum of its coefficients, is it true that
$$
\phi_1(\alpha\cdot f)=\alpha\cdot\phi_1(f)\qquad\text{and}\qquad \phi_1(f+g)=\phi_1(f)+\phi_1(g)
$$
holds?

Comment: could you just put what I need to know. I'm having a hard time trying to figure out what is helpful for answering the question. E.g. what is phi(1)?

Comment: phi(f + g). What do you do next?

Comment: i need to know what f+g is before I do anything else.

Comment: phi(f(x) + g(x)) = ? I need a way to figure out f(x) + g(x) to figure out what phi does to it.

Comment: but i still don't see how any of this helps us determine phi(f(x) + g(x))

Comment: @user9915 I have tried to be more explicit in things.  I hope that this helps; I can't give any more hints without just stating a solution to the problem, and I won't do that.  If there's something you don't get, I would suggest that you stop by your instructor's office hours and see if you can get it cleared up; there's more give and take that way.  Good luck!

Comment: Looking back through this OP's questions, I see that s/he has a habit of not-so-politely demanding answers that explain every single detail.  +1 for holding strong to the principle that the OP must work out some things on his/her own.